# Django taggit: why annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')) counts the number of common tags instead of the total number of tags?

Tags: django

From the tutorials in *Django 2 by Example*, I don't understand:

```
step (2): Why is `Count('tags')` **not** counting 
the total number of tags possessed by that post?
```

This code:

```
# List of similar posts
post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
                              .exclude(id=post.id)
similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                             .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
```

does this:

1. searches similar posts by looking at their common tags.
2. uses Count aggregation function to generate a calculated field `same_tags`.
3. orders the result by the number of shared tags in descending order etc...

I searched Taggit's API reference but it seems irrelevant.

Comment: Because you have a `filter` before the annotate, hene only the tags in common are retained when filtering the number of elements in the `JoinJOIN.

Comment: But isn't the `filter` applied by the Post's object manager, hence only filtering out the posts that do not contain those tags (`post_tags_ids`)? How come it filters both of the unwanted posts and (even) those tags different from `post_tags_ids` in those desirable posts (which implies that the `filter` function here interferes the result which leads to information loss)?? Am I asking a legitimate question here actually?

Comment: no, it is filtering on the aggregates as well, dixit the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand step (2): Why is `Count('tags')` not counting the total number of tags possessed by that post?

Because the `.annotate(..)` clause is used *after* the `.filter(..)` clause. You thus first filter the joined model, and then you count the elements that are still retained.

As described in the [*aggregation* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude):

> When used with an `annotate()` clause, a `filter` has the effect of
>   **constraining the objects for which an annotation is calculated**. For example, you can generate an annotated list of all books that have
>   a title starting with “Django” using the query:
>
> ```
> >>> from django.db.models import Avg, Count
> >>> Book.objects.filter(name__startswith="Django").annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
> ```

You thus create a query that looks like:

```
SELECT post.*
       COUNT(tag.id) AS same_tags
FROM post
INNER JOIN tag
WHERE tag.id IN list_of_tag_ids
  AND post.id != id_of_post
ORDER BY same_tags DESC, post.publish DESC
```